# handleMessageError when registering Teams connector

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm developing a Microsoft Teams custom app that can add connectors to Teams channels.

My connector has been working fine for a few months now, but a few weeks ago, the ability to register new connectors has stopped working:

After clicking “Save” on the connector configuration page, “loading” shows up until it times out (see the console screenshot below).

When I look in the browser console, I see that the outbound request was actually successful and notifySuccess() was called on the save event, but Teams does not register it (see full JS code below).

Also, a handleMessageError message is emitted, but I could not figure out what the issue is.

I tried this in the native app and in Chrome, and a client tried it in another instance of Teams as well.

Is this a bug or a (undocumented?) change in the Teams API?

[Console / UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q90tT.png)

**JSON Error Message:**

```
{
    "seq": 1615787354693,
    "timestamp": 1615793440583,
    "flightSettings": {
        "Name": "ConnectorFrontEndSettings",
        "AriaSDKToken": "d127f72a3abd41c9b9dd94faca947689-d58285e6-3a68-4cab-a458-37b9d9761d35-7033",
        "SPAEnabled": true,
        "ClassificationFilterEnabled": true,
        "ClientRoutingEnabled": true,
        "EnableYammerGroupOption": true,
        "EnableFadeMessage": false,
        "EnableDomainBasedOwaConnectorList": false,
        "EnableDomainBasedTeamsConnectorList": false,
        "DevPortalSPAEnabled": true,
        "ShowHomeNavigationButtonOnConfigurationPage": false,
        "DisableConnectToO365InlineDeleteFeedbackPage": true
    },
    "status": 500,
    "clientType": "SkypeSpaces",
    "connectorType": "fc0ee140-b62a-4947-9af1-d19a66a00af8",
    "name": "handleMessageError"
}
```

**JS code that runs on the connector's configuration page:**

```
    const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const subscriptionApiUrl = "https://XYZ.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/subscriptions/";
    const channelsApiBaseURL = "https://www.example.com/api/library/v2/channels/";
    const defaultChannelParameters = "sorting=latest&language=en&excludeReviews=true";
    const url = new URL(window.location.href);
    const clientId = url.searchParams.get("clientid");
    const clientSecret = url.searchParams.get("clientsecret");
    const teamsSettings = {
      entityId: "Example",
      contentUrl: "https://www.example.com/xyz",
      configName: "Example"
    };
    var saveEvent;
 
    console.log("Example Connector initializing");
    microsoftTeams.initialize();
    microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true); // make Save button enabled
    microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler(handleSaveEvent);
 
    function handleSaveEvent(e) {
      saveEvent = e;
      microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings(teamsSettings);
      microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings(storeSettings);
    }
 
    function storeSettings(settings) {
      XHR.addEventListener("load", reportSuccess);
      XHR.addEventListener("error", reportFailure);
      XHR.open("POST", subscriptionApiUrl);
      XHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      XHR.send(composePayload(settings.webhookUrl));
      console.log("Request to store Example Connector sent");
    }
 
    function composePayload(webhookUrl) {
      return JSON.stringify({
        webhookUrl: webhookUrl,
        gaChannelUrl: channelsApiBaseURL + document.getElementById("ga-channel-id").value + "/items?" + defaultChannelParameters,
        gaClientId: clientId,
        gaClientSecret: clientSecret,
        cronSchedule: "0 " + document.getElementById("time").value + " * * " + document.getElementById("frequency"),
        postNow: document.getElementById("post-now").checked ? true : false
      });
    }
 
    function reportSuccess(e) {
      console.log("Example Connector registered!");
      saveEvent.notifySuccess();
    }
 
    function reportFailure(e) {
      let msg = "Could not connect to subscription API.";
      console.log(msg);
      saveEvent.notifyFailure(msg);
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm seeing the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75229408/notifysuccess-on-saveevent-not-working-seeing-error-in-console

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. I registered the connector and downloaded the generated manifest.json then packaged (with icons) and tried to sideload the zip. I got the same error when trying to "Save".
I then tried to edit the generated manifest using the App Studio (App Studio -> Import an existing app) and this time I got a meaningful error saying the property ***needsIdentity*** is not valid according the schema from the manifest  (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.3/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json)

Removing this property fixed the issue and I was able to save the connector configuration.
I could not find any documentation about this property. I checked the last version of the schema by now (1.8) and it's not there !!

I created an issue : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/2949

Comment: Hi @naepflin, are you still facing the issue.